# copy files in Ubuntu in subfolders

Tags: ubuntu, copy

Lets say I have one folder with 200K files, all files lets say are JPG, now I want to make sub-folders and copy 10K files in each folder. Is it possible in Linux? I want to do this because it is getting failed whenever I try to copy these giant folder into USB. If I can make sub folders then it will be easy, I think.

Comment: Read tag description: `BATCH-FILE` **DOES NOT** mean processing many files!

Answer (score 0):

While it is an interesting task for shell scripting, I would go the other way and use `rsync` to reliably copy files over possible multiple iterations.

Also if the destination device fails, it can be the sign of bad usb cable, flash or filesystem issues.

As the scripting solution I quickly tested this one liner script:

`X=0;num=0; for files in`ls -1`; do dest=sub${X};((num++)); [ -d $dest ] || mkdir $dest; cp -r  "$files" $dest; if ((  $num  >= 10000 )) ; then num=0; X=$(($X+1)); fi;done`

One need to run it in the dir with 200k+ files, it creates subdirs sub, sub1,subX and copies! ( not moves ) the files to these directories. Feel free to adopt for your needs